# How to consume messages from RabbitMQ on nodejs

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I am a new user trying to implement RabbitMQ on my nodejs code. I have referred couple of examples on using it but still unclear on how to use it with real time example. I am trying to use Rabbit MQ to read messages off the queue. How can I read messages from the queue on nodejs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are tutorials for javascript on the website.  Have you even checked them out?  https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

Comment: @djones yes I did  !

Answer (score 0):

Node.js has a massive open-source community that contributes to [npmjs.org](https://npmjs.org). Chances are, someone has already built a module to do what you want to do.

In your case, https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp

From the docs for **queue.subscribe([options,] listener)**:

```
q.subscribe(function (message, headers, deliveryInfo, messageObject) {
    console.log('Got a message with routing key ' + deliveryInfo.routingKey);
});
```

Comment: This is the module I am trying to use on my end but this is just a basic set up. I am looking for more details like how to add a listener and make it listen to the queue to read the messages.

Comment: Their docs are very extensive. https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp#queuesubscribeoptions-listener

Answer (score 0):

the official rabbitmq tutorials offer examples of the basic scenarios, with working code, using Node.js and the `amqp.node` library (aka "amqplib"). i recommend starting there:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html

i also have a complete training guide to go from the ground up, with RabbitMQ and Node.js. The focus is to push toward "microservices", but the core of the material is learning RabbitMQ, first: https://sub.watchmecode.net/guides/microservices-with-rabbitmq/

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking into this, we just released our OSS library for RabbitMQ in Node: BunnyBus (www.github.com/xogroup/bunnybus)

It is a super easy facade that utilizes `amqplib` behind the scenes.

```
const BunnyBus = require('bunnybus');
const  bunnyBus = new BunnyBus({
    protocol : process.env.RABBIT_PROTOCOL,
    user     : process.env.RABBIT_USER,
    password : process.env.RABBIT_PASSWORD,
    server   : process.env.RABBIT_SERVER,
    port     : process.env.RABBIT_PORT,
    vhost    : process.env.RABBIT_V_HOST
});

const messageHandler = {
    'event-name': (message, acknowledge, reject, requeue) => {
        // do your work with the message here

        return acknowledge();
    }
};

// This will auto-connect and create the queue and bindings if they do not exist
bunnyBus.subscribe('queueName', messageHandler)
    .then(() => {
        const myMessage = {/*your contents here*/};
        return bunnyBus.publish(myMessage, { routeKey: 'event-name' });
    });
```